# using 64-bit only vbscript code in vb.net

Tags: vbscript

Anyone know how to execute 64-bit vbscript code in vb.net?
I need to execute some vbscript com component that only has specific 64-bit and 32-bit components and I CANNOT use the 32-bit component on 64-bit computer!
The vbscript code is on my project page: http://kinectmultipoint.codeplex.com
You need the dsf runtime installed to run the vbscript and to run softehcicfg program.
Its code for an mouse emulator that moves the mouse a few inches on screen for 2 seconds and then you see it acting no more.

I plan on creating an mouse emulator for 32-bit and 64-bit computers but the scripting control will not work because the libraries are specifically 64-bit.
 The 32-bit version is fine but i need to work on 64-bit version.

Comment: 32-bit version works but i need 64-bit version so i can get it working on any computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as 64bit or 32bit VBScript code. VBScript is a runtime interpreted scripting language and not compiled code. If you can clarify your question with the correct information you may get more helpful answers.

Comment: I have an  64-bit installer from device simulation framework that installs a com component that only works on 64-bit computers but no 32-bit libraries. But i think in reality the device simulation framework is running 32-bit libraries behind the scenes but the com component that shows up on 32-bit computer doesn't on 64-bit.

Comment: Im talking about microsofts device simulation framework that has this problem because their are no 32-bit components that can be directly reference from 32-bit script control with 64-bit DSF Runtime installer. AS a test try to run the TestGenericHid.wsf script included as sample with dsf runtime to see my point in script control. have a nice version here: http://kinectmultipoint.codeplex.com

Comment: I don't have this code running. But your problem is that you are launching different versions of COM+. If you run:

    c:\Windows\SysWOW64\dcomcnfg.exe

you will get the 32 bit version of COM+ and see the 32bit components. If you run c:\Windows\System32\dcomcnfg.exe you will get the 64bit version of COM+ and see the 64bit components. If you want to access the 32bit components, you will have to run a 32bit binary.

Comment: So that allows me to see the com's library locations! Sweet that will help a lot thank you! I was looking for a com utility but couldnt remember were to look. Thanks its useful for seeing details that are needed to launch com components.

Comment: You need dsf runtime to see the com components though and their is no 32-bit library by itself in 32-bit. Remember that dsfruntime needs to be installed to run my test script. If you know the vbscript scripting interface at all i could tell my app to target it directly instead of using script control but i would have to also tell it to parse it. What recommendations would you give me?

Comment: I really can't answer this question for you since I don't really understand what you're asking. You might consider posting some code in a new question.

Comment: Thanks but i figured out i could just paste the vbscript code into webbrowser control and use webbrowsername.document.scriptinvoke("scriptmethod here") to get the same vbscript to work on seperate computers but if you find a better way to work with my code I have a sample download on http://kinectmultipoint.codeplex.com